# Removing space between 3 HTML columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the code below I have 3 `col-md-4` that I want to reduce the space between to about 25px. I've tried reducing the margin between them along with increasing the padding on the left and right side of the first and last column respectively. The problem with this approach is that when the window size is manipulated it makes the image columns offset because of the increased padding.

HTML:

```
<div class="cards">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>
      Our Expertise.
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <!-- <img> -->
     <!-- <img> -->
     <!-- <img> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <!-- <img> -->
     <!-- <img> -->
     <!-- <img> -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <!-- <img> -->
     <!-- <img> -->
     <!-- <img> -->
     <!-- <img> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', sans-serif;
 }

  .first    {
     padding-left: 200px !important;
  }

  .last {
    padding-right: 200px !important;
  }

  .container {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .header   {
    padding-top: 20px;
  }

  .header h1    {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  .nav li   {
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px;
  }
  .nav li a {
    color: #333;
  }

  .jumbotron {
     background-color: transparent;
     padding-top: 100px;
     padding-bottom: 100px;

  }
  .jumbotron h2     {
     font-size: 50px;
  }
  .jumbotron h2 span    {
     color: #ffc200;
  }

  .banner {
     background-color: #333;
     height: 140px;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 30px;
  }

  .cards {
     background-color: #FFC200;
     text-align: center;
  }

  .cards img {
     margin-bottom: 25px;
     padding: auto;
  }

  .cards h2 {
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 80px; 
  }

  @media (max-width: 992px) {
     .col-md-4 {
     margin: 0 auto 0;
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
  }

  .cards img {
    width: 60%;
   } 
  }

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .header h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

  .nav li {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

  .cards img {
    width: 100%;
   }
 }
```

There are suppose to be images in the columns but because I don't have 10 rep points it wont let me post them.

Comment: I don't see how could anyone possibly help you with the provided information

Comment: I guess the margin appears bigger than it should because there's a space between. Try it with no whitespace between the divs.

Comment: I'd like to see your CSS.

Comment: The columns shouldn't have any spaces between them with the code you have now.

Comment: @vsync What other information should I provide or what can I clarify better?

Comment: @Aloso I edited the HTML to include where the images go. I cant add the actual images since I don't have enough rep. Edited my post to include the CSS.

Comment: @RachelS See my reply to Aloso

Answer (score 0):

Just change the default column padding. You need to keep the total space between the columns an even number, so 24 would be good, you would simply change the default column padding from `15px` to `12px` and override the negative margin on the row as well:

```css
.row {
  margin-left: -12px!important;
  margin-right: -12px!important;
}

div[class*='col-'] {
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
}

.inner {
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="cards">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>
      Our Expertise.
    </h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="inner">Column 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="inner">Column 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="inner">Column 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```